# How to maintain session between two request in mocha

Tags: javascript, rest, session, mocha.js

I am using the mocha testing framework to test rest-api. For maintaining the session I am using **agent** of supertest. I am using sessoin_key to access the **REST-API**. But I think **agent** is using cookies to accessing **REST-API**. But I don't want to use this. Because I my project we are session the other **REST-API** through session_key.

**Rest-API end point is : /rest_api/addCarpenter**
 **Request body to add carpenter:**

```
  Request Body:
  {
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "cooper",
    "session_key": "dshjdhs78237",
  }
```

In request body we are sending session_key, I have written following test case for testing add carpenter but getting   Uncaught AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 0.

```
var supertest = require("supertest");
var assert = require("assert");
var expect = require("chai").expect;

var request = require('supertest'), 
   should = require('chai').should();

describe('Test session', function() {
  var agent = request.agent('http://localhost:8000') ;

  before(function(done){
      agent
        .post('/rest_api/login')
        .send({'username': 'Bill', 'password': 'xyz'})
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          done();
        });
  })

  after(function(done){
      agent
        .get('/rest_api/logout')
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          done();
        });
  })
  describe('test add corpenter', function(){
    it('should return error=1 after login', function (done) {
      agent
        .post('/api/addCarpenter')
        .send({"first_name": "Bill", "last_name": "cooper", "mobile1": 9090907789,})
        .end(function (err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);

          res.body.error.should.equal(0);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Assertion Error:

```
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 0
      + expected - actual

      -1
      +0

      at Test.<anonymous> (justTest.js:38:33)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:156:6)
      at assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:127:12)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:124:5
      at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:785:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:990:12)
      at _stream_readable.js:920:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `session_key` in your request body you should add it by hand to the object that you are sending:

```
.send({"first_name": "Bill", "last_name": "cooper", "mobile1": 9090907789, "session_key": theSessionKey})
```

If you want to keep you test-layout as you have it at the moment I'd introduce this `theSessionKey` at te describe() level, so add it below the declaration of the `agent` variable.

Now set the `theSessionKey` variable in your `before()` function based on the contents of `res` after calling login.

You should null `theSessionKey` in the `after()` part.

Comment: Thanks for reply I have done the same ways, But I was thinking that agent  will take responsibility for it..

Comment: How would 'agent' know that you've implemented sessions based on passing session_key in every request? I don't think you are following some sort of standard, or are you?

Comment: You don't: From looking at the code https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/lib/agent.js you can see agent is only set up to help you with cookie-based scenarios. So you have to do this yourself. Maybe you can create a wrapper to take some duplicate code out, but I don't think it will be that different from my approach described above.